Possible to run express server web application on Amplify?
I would like to migrate our existing Vue/Node web application from Heroku to Amplify. The app runs on an express server (i.e., "start": "node server.js" in the package.json). But it seems that Amplify is not starting the server, and instead using it's own web server. Is it possible to configure Amplify to use the express server instead?

The Vue front-end will be hosted on S3 and delivered via CloudFront. The express server will become a lambdas (or broken into multiple lambdas) that are triggered via API Gateway. Look into Amplify "API" (REST) support. Express should port over easily enough. You don't need to listen on a port.

Why does it not have to listen on a port? Our server.js script processes each application request, to manage security headers, etc., and to dynamically handle some routes. Static routes are then passed off to /dist.

I could be wrong, I have very few details about what you're trying to accomplish. Big picture, the HTTP request (for the REST API) goes to AWS API Gatway (amplify add api). That will map the request to a Lambda (your Express code). The Lambda's handler will be called, examine the request, do something, and return a response. There is no long-running service listening on a port. I'm sure there are many articles covering Express to Lambda.

PS: Once you get the basics working, you can move security header management into API Gateway and/or auth lambdas that run before your express code even gets hit. And not my reply is thinking about 'Express' in terms of backend APIs. If you're focused on hosting the VUE app, just follow the Amplify tutorial for Vue then migrate your frontend into it.
